# When does "You can only post once every 40 minutes." restriction gets waived?

Tags: support

When I try to post a second question soon after having posted a previous one, I get the message "You can only post once every 40 minutes."

When does this restriction gets waived, if ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Meta StackExchange: [The Complete Rate Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

> - Users with < 125 rep on the current site, [40 minutes since their last question anywhere on the network](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265) (This applies to the user's IP address, not their account. If the user shares that IP with other users, they can be limited by the other user asking a question anywhere on the network.)
>
>   [image]
>
>   - Other per-site limits may apply; e.g. on Stack Overflow, new users can only ask once every 90 minutes
>   - Users limited by Anti-Recidivism System, one question per week
>   - Users limited from asking questions for 1 – 7 days based on the performance of their previous questions
>   - Users prevented from asking questions due to the quality filter: one question per 6 months, beginning 6 months after the ban began

In general though questions regarding the how the actual Stack Exchange network works would be better on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) .